# Updating User Password in Django with Class Based Views

Tags: python, django

I'm tring write a view to administrator update a password of another user, using Class Based Views and model SetPasswordForm of Django.

My views.py

```
class UserSetPasswordUpdateView(GroupRequiredMixin, FormView):
    form_class = forms.SetPasswordForm
    model =  User
    template_name = 'app/admin/object_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('portal:admin_user')
    group_required = u"Administrator"

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(UserSetPasswordUpdateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = User.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return kwargs

update_change_password = UserSetPasswordUpdateView.as_view()
```

My urls.py

```
url(r'^app/admin/update-user-pass/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', update_views.update_change_password, name='update_change_password'),
```

And don't show any errors, just go to `success_url`, but the password don't updated.

Answer (score 1):

Your view is based on FormView. This doesn't have any knowledge of model forms, and doesn't do anything with the data other than check that it is valid. SetPasswordForm changes the password when the form is saved, but this view never does this.

You could override `form_valid` to call `form.save()` explicitly, but it would be better to use a more appropriate base class such as UpdateView which will do that for you.

Comment: I changed my view `FormView`to `UpdateView` and got this error `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'`

Comment: I belive that `UpdateView` wait a `fields`, but it don't accept `form_class` with `fields`.